# JFrame bleeds through JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jinternalframe

[image: JFrame bleed through JInternalFrame]

I'm creating a desktop app and I can't figure out why the JFrame is bleeding through the JInternalFrame (see pic). I've tried to include the relevant code below so please disregard missing {}, it runs without errors in the actual application.

```
public class MainJFrame extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2377310559170663631L;
Container cPane;
JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
JPanel deskPanel;
JButton jButtonCreateWLog, jButtonCreateCLog;



public static void main(String args[]) {
    MainJFrame w = new MainJFrame();
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int maxX = screenSize.width - 100;
    int maxY = screenSize.height - 200;
    w.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(maxX, maxY));
    w.setSize(maxX, maxY);
    w.setTitle("Estes Fitness Help");
    w.setVisible(true);
}

public MainJFrame() {
    super("Estes Fitness Help");
    getContentPane().add(desktopPane);
    cPane = getContentPane();
    cPane.setLayout(null);
    initiateComponents();
    initiateMenuBar();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
private void initiateComponents(){

    //Set size to match desktop size
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int maxX = screenSize.width - 100;
    int maxY = screenSize.height - 200;

    //Create panel inside desktop
    deskPanel = new JPanel();
    deskPanel.setName("Weight Log Entry");
    deskPanel.setLayout(null);
    deskPanel.setBackground(new Color(200, 50, 50));

    //button for creating a weight log
    jButtonCreateWLog = new JButton();
    jButtonCreateWLog.setText("Create Weight Log");
    jButtonCreateWLog.setBounds(80, 120, 150, 25);
    jButtonCreateWLog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButtonCreateWLogActionPerformed(e);
      }
    });

    //button for creating a cardio log
    jButtonCreateCLog = new JButton();
    jButtonCreateCLog.setText("Create Cardio Log");
    jButtonCreateCLog.setBounds(250, 120, 150, 25);
    jButtonCreateCLog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButtonCreateCLogActionPerformed(e);
      }
    });

    //add components to deskPanel
    deskPanel.add(jButtonCreateWLog);
    deskPanel.add(jButtonCreateCLog);
    deskPanel.setSize(maxX, maxY);
    cPane.add(deskPanel);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);

}

private void jButtonCreateWLogActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    MainJFrameController desktopPaneC = new MainJFrameController(this);
    desktopPaneC.actionPerformed(e);

}
```

This is the MainJFrameController:

```
public class MainJFrameController implements ActionListener{

private MainJFrame desktopFrame;

public MainJFrameController(){

}

public MainJFrameController(MainJFrame desktopFrame){
    this.desktopFrame = desktopFrame;   
    desktopFrame.getCreateWLogButton().addActionListener(this);
    desktopFrame.getCreateCLogButton().addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Create Weight Log")){
        getCreateWLogButton_actionPerformed(e);
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Create Cardio Log")){
        getCreateCLogButton_actionPerformed(e);
    }
}

private void getCreateWLogButton_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    StoreWeightLogJFrame SWLJFrame = new StoreWeightLogJFrame();
    SWLJFrame.pack();
    SWLJFrame.setVisible(true);
    desktopFrame.add(SWLJFrame);

}
}
```

This is the WeightLog JInternalFrame

```
public class StoreWeightLogJFrame extends JInternalFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7750452209025354283L;

JPanel jPanel1;
JLabel jLabelSets, jLabelReps, jLabelWeight;
JTextField jTextFieldSets, jTextFieldReps, jTextFieldWeight;
JButton jButtonSaveWLog;

public StoreWeightLogJFrame() {
    super("Store Weight Log");
    initiateComponents();
    this.add(jPanel1);
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 505, 505);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.pack();
    this.setClosable(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    System.out.println("StoreWeightLogJFrame initialized");
}
private void initiateComponents(){

    jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    jLabelSets = new JLabel();
    jTextFieldSets = new JTextField();
    jLabelReps = new JLabel();
    jTextFieldReps = new JTextField();
    jLabelWeight = new JLabel();
    jTextFieldWeight = new JTextField();
    jButtonSaveWLog = new JButton();
    jPanel1.setName("Weight Log Entry");
    jPanel1.setLayout(null);
    jPanel1.setBackground(new Color(255, 50, 50));

    jLabelSets.setText("Sets: ");
    jLabelSets.setBounds(25, 25, 100, 50);
    jTextFieldSets.setText("3");
    jTextFieldSets.setBounds(80, 40, 25, 25);


    jLabelReps.setText("Reps: ");
    jLabelReps.setBounds(25, 60, 100, 50);
    jTextFieldReps.setText("10");
    jTextFieldReps.setBounds(80, 75, 25, 25);

    jLabelWeight.setText("Weight: ");
    jLabelWeight.setBounds(25, 110, 50, 25);
    jTextFieldWeight.setText("225");
    jTextFieldWeight.setBounds(80, 110, 30, 25);

    jButtonSaveWLog.setText("Save Log");
    jButtonSaveWLog.setBounds(40, 150, 100, 25);
    jButtonSaveWLog.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButtonSaveWLogActionPerformed(e);
    }
    });

    jPanel1.add(jLabelSets);
    jPanel1.add(jTextFieldSets);
    jPanel1.add(jLabelReps);
    jPanel1.add(jTextFieldReps);
    jPanel1.add(jLabelWeight);
    jPanel1.add(jTextFieldWeight);
    jPanel1.add(jButtonSaveWLog);
    jPanel1.setBounds(5, 5, 500, 550);

}
```

Comment: It appears that you're having a z-ordering issues

Answer (score 0):

```
getContentPane().add(desktopPane);
cPane = getContentPane();
```

First you add the desktop pane to the content pane.

```
cPane.add(deskPanel);
```

Then later you add the deskPanel to the content pane.

Because you are using a null layout you have added two components to the same container and the button will display when the mouse hover over it.

Don't know exactly what you are trying to do but I would guess you should:

1. not use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout manager
2. display a "button panel" and the "desktop pane" on the content pane using an appropriate layout manager (BorderLayout) to control the location of each component.

So the basic logic is something like:

```
JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
frame.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now if you want your "buttons" to appear on the frame you can create another panel for your buttons:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(theFirstButton);
buttonPanel.add(theSecondButton);
frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Now the frame will contain a panel with the buttons at the top of the frame and the desktop pane will be located below this panel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I will check out your link once I'm back from travelling and see if I can make it work.